# Rearrange numbers and change design of horner scheme

Tags: math-mode

I am using the `polynom` package in order to create a horner scheme for two polynomials. The default scheme looks like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\[ \polyhornerscheme[x=1]{x^3+3x^2-2x+5} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way, by using the `polynom` package, to custom the `\polyhornerscheme` command so it will change the position of number 1 as wel as the design of the scheme to look more like a tabular like the following picture?

[image]

Comment: Why not just write it as a `tabular` *without* [`polynom`](//ctan.org/pkg/polynom)?

Comment: The `polynom` package computes automaticaly the coefficients. I don't know how to create such a command with `tabular`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modification of my code for [Horner scheme with a tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165517/)

The syntax is

```
\horner*[<length>]{<coefficients>}{<evaluated at>}
```

where the `*` means “hide the computation”, `<length>` is the width of the cells (default 2em), `<coefficients>` is the list of coefficients (only integers) of the polynomial and `<evaluated at>` is the point where the polynomial is evaluated at.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering$}p{#1}<{$}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165517/
\NewDocumentCommand{\horner}{sO{2em}mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \bool_set_false:N \l_silke_show_bool }
   { \bool_set_true:N \l_silke_show_bool }
  \silke_horner:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\bool_new:N \l_silke_show_bool
\seq_new:N \l_silke_top_seq
\seq_new:N \l_silke_middle_seq
\seq_new:N \l_silke_bottom_seq
\seq_new:N \l_silke_temp_seq
\int_new:N \l_silke_degree_int
\tl_new:N \l_silke_remainder_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \silke_horner:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_silke_top_seq { , } { #2 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_silke_degree_int { \seq_count:N \l_silke_top_seq }
  \seq_clear:N \l_silke_middle_seq
  \seq_clear:N \l_silke_bottom_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_silke_middle_seq { }
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_silke_bottom_seq
   {
    \int_to_arabic:n { \seq_item:Nn \l_silke_top_seq { 1 } }
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 2 } { 1 } { \l_silke_degree_int }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_silke_middle_seq
     {
      \int_to_arabic:n { \seq_item:Nn \l_silke_bottom_seq { ##1 - 1 } * #3 }
     }
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_silke_bottom_seq
     {
      \int_to_arabic:n
       {
        \seq_item:Nn \l_silke_top_seq { ##1 }
        +
        \seq_item:Nn \l_silke_middle_seq { ##1 }
       }
     }
   }
  \silke_print_scheme:nn { #1 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \silke_print_scheme:nn #1 #2
 {
  \bool_if:NF \l_silke_show_bool
   {
    \silke_phantom:N \l_silke_middle_seq
    \silke_phantom:N \l_silke_bottom_seq
   }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_silke_bottom_seq \l_silke_remainder_tl
  \begin{tabular}{ *{\int_eval:n {\l_silke_degree_int-1}}{|C{#1}} || C{#1} | C{#1} | }
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l_silke_top_seq { & } & #2 \tabularnewline
  \hline
  \seq_use:Nn \l_silke_middle_seq { & } \tabularnewline
  \cline{1-\l_silke_degree_int}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_silke_bottom_seq { & } & 
  \l_silke_remainder_tl \tabularnewline
  \cline{1-\l_silke_degree_int}
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \silke_phantom:N #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \silke_temp_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn #1 { \seq_put_right:Nn \silke_temp_seq { \phantom{##1} } }
  \seq_set_eq:NN #1 \silke_temp_seq
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\horner{1,3,-2,5}{1}

\bigskip

\horner{3,2,-5,-10}{2}

\bigskip

\horner*{3,2,-5,-10}{2}

\bigskip

\horner[3em]{1,5,100,100,5,1}{-1}

\end{document}
```

[image]